# factory not returning object in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get the results out of a factory to my controller.

So far I've been failing, everything seems to be fine inside the factory itself, I can make console.log of the results and it displays just fine.

Any pointers?

My factory at the moment:

```js
mainApp.factory('statusFinder', ['jsonQueryStations', 'timeConverter', function(jsonQueryStations, timeConverter){
  var findTheTime = timeConverter.getTime();
  var generator = function(){
      return jsonQueryStations.stationData().then(function(result){
      if (result.station[findTheTime]>result.station.Average){
        return "Station is busy";
        } else{
        return "Station is quiet";
        }
      });
    }
  return {
    status: function(){
      return generator();
    }
    }
}])
```

And my controller at the moment look like so :

```js
mainApp.controller('stuff', ['$scope', 'statusFinder', function($scope, statusFinder){
 var data = statusFinder.status();
 $scope.testing = data;
}])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can catch the promise from controller instead of the factory. just return the `jsonQueryStations.stationData()` only in factory.

```
mainApp.factory('statusFinder', ['jsonQueryStations', 'timeConverter', function(jsonQueryStations, timeConverter){
   var generator = function(){
      return jsonQueryStations.stationData()
   }
   return {
    status: function(){
      return generator();
    }
   }
}])
```

Now in the controller catch the promise like this

```
mainApp.controller('stuff', ['$scope', 'statusFinder', function($scope, statusFinder) {
    var findTheTime = timeConverter.getTime();
    statusFinder.status().then(function(result) {
        if (result.station[findTheTime] > result.station.Average) {
            $scope.testing = "Station is busy";
        } else {
            $scope.testing = "Station is quiet";
        }
    });
}])
```

Comment: Thanks, I did something similar previously, I am just trying to move my functions out of the controllers now in order to tidy things up, is that not something I can do from the factory alone then ?

Comment: in your question http return a promise and controller dosn't wait for the promise since promise catch from the controller. This is the proper way to do

Comment: also note that avoid anti-pattern. it will create a another custom promise inside the promise and it will make a mess

Comment: @Blimeys nice. make sure to mark as answer it this helped